# Macosx 10.7 sdk unable to find "stdarg.h"

Tags: xcode, intel, core-foundation

Hi i have a project that compile just fine with 10.6 sdk.
I'm on xcode 3 on lion.
I compile with icc.

Now i'd like to pass it to the 10.7 sdk, but i have this error :

/Applications/XCode3/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:12:0 catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdarg.h"

I have tried to manually find and set the path to this file (there are many) but it give me more & more errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In sdk 10.7 stdarg.h not exist. You have a two ways:
delete #include  from your source
or copy/create new like this:

```
/* This file is public domain.  */
/* GCC uses its own copy of this header */
#if defined(__GNUC__)
//#include_next <stdarg.h> /* originaly uncomment */
#elif defined(__MWERKS__)
#include "mw_stdarg.h"
#else
//#error "This header only supports __MWERKS__." /* originaly uncomment */
#endif
```

icc 2011 dont contain this to.
in BSD look like this, but uncomment.

edit:
Or try without ICC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES

Old source stdarg.h

```
 /* Copyright (C) 1989, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This file is part of GCC.

GCC is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option)
any later version.

GCC is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with GCC; see the file COPYING.  If not, write to
the Free Software Foundation, 59 Temple Place - Suite 330,
Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.  */

/* As a special exception, if you include this header file into source
   files compiled by GCC, this header file does not by itself cause
   the resulting executable to be covered by the GNU General Public
   License.  This exception does not however invalidate any other
   reasons why the executable file might be covered by the GNU General
   Public License.  */

/*
 * ISO C Standard:  7.15  Variable arguments  <stdarg.h>
 */

#ifndef _STDARG_H
#ifndef _ANSI_STDARG_H_
#ifndef __need___va_list
#define _STDARG_H
#define _ANSI_STDARG_H_
#endif /* not __need___va_list */
#undef __need___va_list

/* Define __gnuc_va_list.  */

#ifndef __GNUC_VA_LIST
#define __GNUC_VA_LIST
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
#endif

/* Define the standard macros for the user,
   if this invocation was from the user program.  */
#ifdef _STDARG_H

#define va_start(v,l)   __builtin_va_start(v,l)
#define va_end(v)   __builtin_va_end(v)
#define va_arg(v,l) __builtin_va_arg(v,l)
#if !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) || __STDC_VERSION__ + 0 >= 199900L
#define va_copy(d,s)    __builtin_va_copy(d,s)
#endif
#define __va_copy(d,s)  __builtin_va_copy(d,s)

/* Define va_list, if desired, from __gnuc_va_list. */
/* We deliberately do not define va_list when called from
   stdio.h, because ANSI C says that stdio.h is not supposed to define
   va_list.  stdio.h needs to have access to that data type, 
   but must not use that name.  It should use the name __gnuc_va_list,
   which is safe because it is reserved for the implementation.  */

#ifdef _HIDDEN_VA_LIST  /* On OSF1, this means varargs.h is "half-loaded".  */
#undef _VA_LIST
#endif

#ifdef _BSD_VA_LIST
#undef _BSD_VA_LIST
#endif

#if defined(__svr4__) || (defined(_SCO_DS) && !defined(__VA_LIST))
/* SVR4.2 uses _VA_LIST for an internal alias for va_list,
   so we must avoid testing it and setting it here.
   SVR4 uses _VA_LIST as a flag in stdarg.h, but we should
   have no conflict with that.  */
#ifndef _VA_LIST_
#define _VA_LIST_
#ifdef __i860__
#ifndef _VA_LIST
#define _VA_LIST va_list
#endif
#endif /* __i860__ */
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
#ifdef _SCO_DS
#define __VA_LIST
#endif
#endif /* _VA_LIST_ */
#else /* not __svr4__ || _SCO_DS */

/* The macro _VA_LIST_ is the same thing used by this file in Ultrix.
   But on BSD NET2 we must not test or define or undef it.
   (Note that the comments in NET 2's ansi.h
   are incorrect for _VA_LIST_--see stdio.h!)  */
#if !defined (_VA_LIST_) || defined (__BSD_NET2__) || defined (____386BSD____) || defined (__bsdi__) || defined (__sequent__) || defined (__FreeBSD__) || defined(WINNT)
/* The macro _VA_LIST_DEFINED is used in Windows NT 3.5  */
#ifndef _VA_LIST_DEFINED
/* The macro _VA_LIST is used in SCO Unix 3.2.  */
#ifndef _VA_LIST
/* The macro _VA_LIST_T_H is used in the Bull dpx2  */
#ifndef _VA_LIST_T_H
/* The macro __va_list__ is used by BeOS.  */
#ifndef __va_list__
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
#endif /* not __va_list__ */
#endif /* not _VA_LIST_T_H */
#endif /* not _VA_LIST */
#endif /* not _VA_LIST_DEFINED */
#if !(defined (__BSD_NET2__) || defined (____386BSD____) || defined (__bsdi__) || defined (__sequent__) || defined (__FreeBSD__))
#define _VA_LIST_
#endif
#ifndef _VA_LIST
#define _VA_LIST
#endif
#ifndef _VA_LIST_DEFINED
#define _VA_LIST_DEFINED
#endif
#ifndef _VA_LIST_T_H
#define _VA_LIST_T_H
#endif
#ifndef __va_list__
#define __va_list__
#endif

#endif /* not _VA_LIST_, except on certain systems */

#endif /* not __svr4__ */

#endif /* _STDARG_H */

#endif /* not _ANSI_STDARG_H_ */
#endif /* not _STDARG_H */
```